# I get error when delete data from my table

Tags: php, mysql

This is my script delete.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
include_once 'connect.php';

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['delete']);

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM tabel WHERE id=$id");
$query_execute = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if ($query_execute) {
    header("location: ../task.php?qdel=success");
} else {
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
    header("location: ../task.php?edel=error");
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

When I click delete, the page does not redirect. I get this error:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1".

But when I click back in my browser, the row is deleted. What am I missing?

Comment: no i use tabel as table name

Comment: please show your table schema.

Comment: This is open to sql injection attacks. Switching to using prepared statements will most likely also solve the problem you are having.

Comment: thanks @IncredibleHat... it work fine when i'm using prepare statement... thanks for the advice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using this code... prepare statement work fine in my case...

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
   include 'connect.php';
   $id = $_GET['delete'];
   $deleteString = "DELETE FROM penempatan WHERE id = ?";
   $preparedDeleteStmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $deleteString);
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($preparedDeleteStmt, 'i', $id);

    if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($preparedDeleteStmt)) {
        mysqli_close($conn);
        die("The system is not available, try again later");
        header("location: ../tugas.php?edel=error");
    } 

    if(mysqli_stmt_store_result($preparedDeleteStmt)) {
        header("location: ../tugas.php?qdel=success");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: yes... i just switch to using prepare statement as u said... and then it works...